# How to check that attributes are unique with RelaxNG?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, relaxng

With RelaxNG, can I check whether or not the value of an attribute is unique within an enclosing element?

For example, this `castle` should validate:

```
<castle>
  <room>
    <door to="North" />
    <door to="South" />
  </room>
  <room>
    <door to="North" />
  </room>
</castle>
```

But this should not (duplicate door in same `room`):

```
<castle>
  <room>
    <door to="Dungeon" />
    <door to="Dungeon" />
  </room>
</castle>
```

I'm using RelaxNG (compact). I don't know the attribute values 'ahead of time', only that they should be unique within a `room`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To my knowledge this can't be done in pure RELAX NG. You could use (embedded) Schematron, as we did for the [Citation Style Language schema](https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/blob/master/csl.rnc). If you do take this route, note that not all RELAX NG validators parse embedded Schematron, and that support for standalone Schematron schemas is also limited. E.g. the popular [Jing](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/jing.html) XML validator only supports the older Schematron 1.5 version, not the newer ISO Schematron.

For our project, where we use Jing, we use a [script](https://github.com/citation-style-language/utilities/blob/master/style-qc.sh) to first convert our RELAX NG Compact schema to the RELAX NG XML format (with [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html)), then extract the Schematron rules from the RELAX NG XML schema into a standalone Schematron schema (with [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) and the [RNG2Schtrn.xsl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/citation-style-language/utilities/master/RNG2Schtrn.xsl) XSLT style sheet), and finally validate against the extracted Schematron schema with Jing.

If this hasn't scared you off, I cobbled together the following Schematron 1.5 schema for your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron">
  <sch:pattern name="duplicateAttributeValues">
    <sch:rule context="//room/door[@to]">
      <sch:report test="preceding-sibling::door/@to = @to">Warning: @to values should be unique for a given room.</sch:report>
    </sch:rule>
  </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

When run on the following XML document,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<castle>
  <room>
    <door to="North"/>
    <door to="South"/>
    <door to="West"/>
  </room>
  <room>
    <door to="West"/>
    <door to="North"/>
    <door to="West"/>
  </room>
</castle>
```

[Jing will report](https://validator.nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2Frmzelle%2F3bb7aadc616adb3d2da2239e306bf611%2Fraw%2F1439533a09d7c88b6d5a38f5462985f86647b8fc%2Ftest.xml&schema=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2Frmzelle%2Fab13632606c4c5d250f19f37401375d9%2Fraw%2F4c743719638c7a7c1d019ec9019885a122de794d%2Fschema.sch&parser=xml&laxtype=yes&showsource=yes)

> Error: Warning: @to values should be unique for a given room.
>   From line 11, column 5; to line 11, column 21
>   `th"/>↩    <door to="West"/>↩  </r`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll look into Schematron.