# Can libxml2 handle RELAX NG Schemata with embedded Schematron rules?

Tags: xml, schematron, relaxng

I've seen recommendations to embed schematron rules inside of a RELAX NG schema so as to get XSD 1.1-like assertions. The problem is that it's unclear to me to what extent, if any, this is actually supported in tooling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [command line validator supporting relax ng Schemas with embedded iso Schematron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906793/command-line-validator-supporting-relax-ng-schemas-with-embedded-iso-schematron). That's the answer, basically - I don't think there is a tool that can handle embedded Schematron out of the box.